# is it possible to download material icons css file?

Tags: angular, angular-material

After installing angular material, the following were added to index.html:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there a way to download these css file and reference locally?

Comment: You can put that URL directly in your browser and see the file it refers to. You can also save that file if you want to your PC. There are referenced files within the style sheets and if you want those you will have to change the source file after downloading a local copy.

Comment: You could also check the node_modules map, see `.\node_modules\@angular\material\icon`

Answer (score 0):

There is a different way.
You can download the svg files from http://material.io/resources/icons and store them in your assets folder and then use them like this

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example thumbs up SVG icon"></mat-icon>
```

You have to register them first. Here is my service for doing it:

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
  import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon'
  import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'

  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
  })
  export class SvgToIconService {

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    constructor(private _iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { } //ctor

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    /**
     * Add custom svg to Material Icons
     * @param title Html reference
     * @param pathToSvg Location of SVG file
     */
    addIconToRegistry(title: string, pathToSvg: string) {

      this._iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(title, this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(pathToSvg))

    } //addIconToRegistry


    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------//


    /**
     * Add custom svg to Material Icons
     * @param title Html reference
     * @param pathToSvg Location of SVG file
     */
    addIconsToRegistry(icons: SvgIcon[]) {

      icons.forEach((icon) =>
        this._iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
          icon.title,
          this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(icon.path)
        )
      )

    } //addIconToRegistry


    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------//


    /**
     * Register all the icons in the shared\assets\material-icons folder. 
     * Remember to add shared\assets\material-icons to your project assets in angular.json.
     * @param folderPath where to find the icons (must end with '/') - default 'assets/images/material-icons/'
     */
    registerAllIcons(folderPath: string = 'assets/images/material-icons/') {
      

      this.addIconToRegistry('account_circle', folderPath + 'account_circle.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('addchart', folderPath + 'addchart.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('add_check', folderPath + 'add_check.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('add_circle', folderPath + 'add_circle.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('add_credit_card', folderPath + 'add_credit_card.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('add_email', folderPath + 'add_email.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('add_notes', folderPath + 'add_notes.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('add_payment', folderPath + 'add_payment.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('analytics', folderPath + 'analytics.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('anchor', folderPath + 'anchor.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('business', folderPath + 'business.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('chevron-down', folderPath + 'chevron-down.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('check_circle', folderPath + 'check_circle.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('check_euro', folderPath + 'check_euro.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('close', folderPath + 'close.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('cloud_upload', folderPath + 'cloud_upload.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('columns', folderPath + 'columns.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('compass-outline', folderPath + 'compass-outline.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('contact_support', folderPath + 'contact_support.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('content_copy', folderPath + 'content_copy.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('copyright', folderPath + 'copyright.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('credit_card', folderPath + 'credit_card.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('description', folderPath + 'description.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('edit_user', folderPath + 'edit_user.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('email', folderPath + 'email.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('error', folderPath + 'error.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('engineering', folderPath + 'engineering.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('euro', folderPath + 'euro.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('excel_logo', folderPath + 'excel_logo.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('facebook_circle', folderPath + 'facebook_circle.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('hangfire_icon', folderPath + 'hangfire_icon.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('home', folderPath + 'home.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('help', folderPath + 'help.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('instagram_outline', folderPath + 'instagram_outline.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('get_app', folderPath + 'get_app.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('menu', folderPath + 'menu.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('notes', folderPath + 'notes.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('nurse', folderPath + 'nurse.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('payments', folderPath + 'payments.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('people', folderPath + 'people.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('phone', folderPath + 'phone.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('products', folderPath + 'products.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('pwd-reset', folderPath + 'pwd-reset.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('refresh', folderPath + 'refresh.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('reset_pwd', folderPath + 'pwd-reset.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('school', folderPath + 'school.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('twitter_bird', folderPath + 'twitter_bird.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('unfold_more', folderPath + 'unfold_more.svg')
      this.addIconToRegistry('wifi_off', folderPath + 'wifi_off.svg')


      this.addIconToRegistry('person_add copy', folderPath + 'person_add copy.svg')

    }//registerAllIcons

  } //Cls

  //======================================================================================================//

  export class SvgIcon {

    /**
     * Class for encapsulating an SVG icon file.
     * @param title Name of Icon: This will be used in the HTML to identify the icon
     * @param path Where is the image located
     */
    constructor(public title: string, public path: string) { } //ctor

  } //Cls

  //======================================================================================================//
```

Then use the service in app.component.ts

```
constructor(
   svgToIcon: SvgToIconService
) {
 svgToIcon.registerAllIcons()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
You may follow the steps below :

1. The best way to download the Google Fonts is to use the free [Google Webfonts Helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts). First choose the font you want and then select the styles you need.
2. Upload the Font Files to your server (or in your case locally which is the project folder)
3. Add these fonts to your CSS